# Apache / httpd not starting automatically on boot

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, configuration, httpd

I have apache2 installed on Amazon Linux AMI release 2012.03. I'm able to start it manually just fine, without any errors using `/etc/init.d/httpd start`. However, it doesn't start automatically when the machine is booted up.

It appears that everything is configured properly in my rc*.d directories. Here's the result of `find /etc/rc.d -name "*httpd*" | xargs ls -l`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3371 Feb 16  2012 /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 14  2012 /etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K15httpd -> ../init.d/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 14  2012 /etc/rc.d/rc1.d/K15httpd -> ../init.d/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 14  2012 /etc/rc.d/rc2.d/K15httpd -> ../init.d/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 14  2012 /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/K15httpd -> ../init.d/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 14  2012 /etc/rc.d/rc4.d/K15httpd -> ../init.d/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 14  2012 /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/K15httpd -> ../init.d/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Apr 14  2012 /etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K15httpd -> ../init.d/httpd
```

I understand that I can put the `/etc/init.d/httpd start` command into `/etc/rc.local`, but isn't that a workaround? Why isn't it starting automatically? Other stuff in the rc*.d directories starts just fine on bootup (mongod, postfix, etc). Thanks!

Comment: Mike, I think you can use chkconfig --list and chkconfig on with the Amazon AMI distro.

Comment: `chkconfig --list` shows `httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off` ... so how do I turn them on? Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use chkconfig to manage the runlevels under which you want this service to start.

Usually **chkconfig httpd on** does the job.

Comment: What if that doesn't work?

Comment: @PaulSheldrake are you running an OS that uses systemd by any chance? For example, Linuxes in the Red Hat 7 family now use systemd. In that case you want `systemctl enable httpd`

Comment: @JasonAzze I'm using centos 6.5.

Comment: @JasonAzze If you're interested in taking a look
https://github.com/paulsheldrake/vagrant/blob/master/scripts/provision.sh#L37

Comment: @PaulSheldrake what is the failure mode? If you issue `chkconfig --list httpd` is it "on" for runlevels 2-5? I wonder if httpd is trying to start but immediately stopping because of a bad httpd config. Is there evidence in the logs?

Comment: Yes, the run levels show correctly.   There is nothing in the logs from what I can tell

Answer (score 7):

You do not have any "S" links. All the "K" are shutdown only. Add links with same name, just replace the K with S.

> "In general, the system starts commands that begin with the letter "S"
>   and stops commands that begin with the letter "K." Commands that begin
>   with the letter "K" run only when the system is changing run levels
>   from a higher to a lower level. Commands that begin with the letter
>   "S" run in all cases."

If using chkconfig, see "man chkconfig". For your case:

```
chkconfig --level 2345 httpd on
```

should do.